# Magento2 Enterprise: Can we add Special Price From Date and Special Price To Date in Enterprise Edition

Tags: custom, special-price, magento2-enterprise

i want to add **Special Price From Date** and **Special Price To Date** in Enterprise Edition.By default this feature is not available in E.E but available in C.E 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can display those two hidden fields. Many solution elsewhere mention to override the `vendor/magento/module-catalog-staging/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`. But this solution does not work. I'm mentioning the solution which I applied. The two fields are hidden using the Modifier Pools, so we would have to override those modifiers pool.

1. override modifier in your `Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

   ```
   <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="eav" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
               </item>
               <item name="advanced-pricing" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="class" xsi:type="string">catalogProductAdvancedPricingModifierCustom</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">90</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </virtualType>

   //And then define the scope for advance pricing form
   <virtualType name="catalogProductAdvancedPricingModifierCustom" type="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedPricing">
      <arguments>
         <argument name="scopeName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form</argument>
       </arguments>
   </virtualType>
   ```
2. Now create the modifier  `Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav` and override the parent construct to remove the attributes from `$attributesToEliminate` array

   ```
   namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

   use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav as CatalogEav;

   class Eav extends CatalogEav
   {
      public function __construct(
        ...
        $attributesToDisable = [],
        $attributesToEliminate = [],
        CompositeConfigProcessor $wysiwygConfigProcessor = null,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig = null,
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory = null,
        AuthorizationInterface $auth = null
      ) {
          unset($attributesToEliminate['special_from_date']);
          unset($attributesToEliminate['special_to_date']);
          parent::__construct(
            ...
            $attributesToDisable,
            $attributesToEliminate,
            $wysiwygConfigProcessor,
            $scopeConfig,
            $attributeCollectionFactory,
            $auth
         );
      }
   }
   ```
3. In `Magento\CatalogStaging\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedPricing` file the `container_special_from_date` and `container_special_to_date` are unset from meta. so we will now override the `modifyMeta` function in our module.  `Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedPricing`

   ```
   namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

   use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedPricing as CatalogAdvancedPricing;

   class AdvancedPricing extends CatalogAdvancedPricing
   {
       public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
       {
          $this->meta = parent::modifyMeta($meta);
          return $this->meta;
       }
   }
   ```

> If you want to display these attributes in catalog staging - schedule update form also. then override the modifier virtual type in the same way.

- Add you modifier `Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

  ```
   <virtualType name="Magento\CatalogStaging\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
           <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="eav" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CatalogStaging\Eav</item>
                         <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                     </item>
                     <item name="advanced-pricing" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedPricing</item>
                         <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">90</item>
                </item>
           </argument>
        </arguments>
   </virtualType>
   //And then define the scope for advance pricing form
   <type name="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedPricing">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="scopeName" xsi:type="string">catalogstaging_update_form.catalogstaging_update_form</argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
  ```
- Add your eav modifier file to override `CatalogStaging` Eav modifier - `Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CatalogStaging\Eav`

  ```
   namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CatalogStaging;

   use Magento\CatalogStaging\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav as CatalogEav;

   class Eav extends CatalogEav
   {
      public function __construct(
        ...
        $attributesToDisable = [],
        $attributesToEliminate = [],
        CompositeConfigProcessor $wysiwygConfigProcessor = null,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig = null,
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory = null,
        AuthorizationInterface $auth = null
      ) {
          unset($attributesToEliminate['special_from_date']);
          unset($attributesToEliminate['special_to_date']);
          parent::__construct(
            ...
            $attributesToDisable,
            $attributesToEliminate,
            $wysiwygConfigProcessor,
            $scopeConfig,
            $attributeCollectionFactory,
            $auth
         );
      }
   }
  ```

Comment: I have tried this code but it did not work... Can you please share your module so I can try that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure Pramod. Also it will be helpful if you can share the error you are facing.

Comment: there was Argument error when I was trying to created Advance Price section.

Comment: Thank you @AfreenSheikh, I confirmed that the solution works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @DucTo

Answer (score 0):

By default this functionality is not available for the EE edition of Magento2, You can check the below URL for more details :

https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/issues/391

Comment: Yeah i know, but how can i override this feature in Enterprise edition ? And why this feature remove from Enterprise Edition can you Elaborate please .

Comment: Yes you can do this very easily, create two new date attribute from admin.
further create your own helper function and getProductCollection with these two date filter.